# How to get data from unrelated entities using Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

[image]

I have these three entities which are not related. How can i get the salary of an employee. I want something like this :

```
Select C.salary FROM Employee A, Department B, Salaries C Where A.id=B.empid AND B.id=C.deptid AND A.id=12
```

i need to do the same above operation in core data.

Comment: Core Data is not a database. You should define relationships between the entities. Then your task becomes trivial: `salaries = employee.department.salaries;`

Comment: @MartinR i'm aware of that dude, however the problem is in such a way that the model was built in such a way that every entity is unrelated and i don't have the permissions to edit it. so some how i need to make it work. and also i came to know that it is possible but not how.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggested, the easy way is to set up the needed relationships and traverse them.

But if you don't have the permission to alter the model, you need to work and filter managed in memory object you own once retrieved. In other words, you need to set up `NSFetchRequest`s with the correct `NSPredicate`s.

For example, to retrieve the department for a given employee.

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Department"]; 
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"empid", @(12)];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *departments = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(departments) {
    // do a NSLog for departments here to see what you have
    // here you can access deptid for each department you retrieve
    // and with that value run another request against Salaries
    // e.g. NSManagedObject* department = [departments lastObject];
    //      NSNumber* deptid = [department valueForKey:@"deptid"]   
} else {
    // handle error here

}
```

Other part is left as excersise ;)

Comment: Thanks dude, thats what i'm actually doing it right now. I'm looking for an alternative for performance reasons. Don't we have any programatical approach which can manually set and remove relationships as needed..